# How to show error in Jetpack Compose OutlinedTextview?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

In `OutlinedTextField` I want to show error and use this code:

```
OutlinedTextField(
    value = email,
    isError = emailContainsError,
    label = { Text(emailErrorText) }
)
```

but it gives me the following result

[image]

I got the desired result only when get focus:

[image]

How to show the error without focusing?

Comment: Are you setting `email= ""` in case of error?

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti no

Comment: It is the default behaviour of the `Label`. It is collapsed when the field is focused or when the field is empty.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti how can I customize it so that my error appears as in the second screen?